# Models for Long-Term Time-Series Forecasting and Pattern Recognition

Tags: time-series, forecasting, artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithms

I'm trying to find a solution for long-term electricity hourly prices forecasting. Explaining simply, I have some data from 2018 - 2021 containing Demand, Renewable Generation, Hydropower Generation, System Losses, Energy Exchange, and Electricity Prices for each Energy Submarket (all this in hourly format). What I want to answer is: is possible to create a model to predict the prices for long-term or mid-term forecasting that identify the correlation on the Data?

**For example, if I increase the Renewable Generation over the next ten years and maintain the other input variables as it is, what's the electricity hourly price?**

Is there any model that can identify, learn, and understand the data pattern and achieve this prediction? I had looked into LSTM and RNNs but sounds like that they are used in short-term forecasting.

Comment: The two go-to references are [Weron (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2014.08.008) and [Nowotarski & Weron (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rser.2017.05.234), you should read them first. That said, longer-term electricity price forecasting is truly hard, because prices are *heavily* driven by politics. I would assume the upcoming federal election in Germany to be *THE* main driver for the next years' prices in Germany.

Comment: You may want to read about ECMs (Error Correction Models), which model both the long-term dynamics (via cointegrated relationships) and short-term dynamics.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you for the references, I will take a look for sure!

Comment: @ColorStatistics I've never heard about ECMs before, do you have any references or software examples for that? I've seen that is possible to work with it using the statsmodels package.

Comment: @lrcb: You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model